# Spring HATEOAS doesn't generate _embedded and _link properties in the response

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-hateoas

After upgrade SpringBoot from 1.5.4 to 2.1.7, the existing Spring HATEOAS code does no longer generate '_embedded' and '_link' in the response, instead it generates 'embedded' and 'link'. I need help to find the root cause of this, and how to fix it. Thank you.

Here is a sample of response payload:

```
{
  "embedded": {
     "orders": [
       {
         "id": 3172,
         "orderNumber": 148700990741,
         "status": "FINISHED",
         "userId": "ffffffff5e7c13a4da4a9d0132e95f73",
         "createdAt": "2020-03-26T02:31:32.263Z",
         "updatedAt": "2020-03-26T02:31:38.853Z",
         "createdBy": "ffffffff57acb9e5e4b0e06a0a570080",
         "addresses": [],
         "updatedBy": "ffffffff57acb9e5e4b0e06a0a570080",
         "successUrl": "http://example.com/success",
         "cancelUrl": "http://example.com/cancel",
         "link": {
           "self": {
             "href": "http://local.dev-openclass.com:8088/v1/orders/3172"
           },
           "order": {
             "href": "http://local.dev-openclass.com:8088/v1/orders/3172"
           },
           "transactions": {
             "href": "http://local.dev-openclass.com:8088/v1/orders/3172/transactions"
           }
        }
      }
    ]
 },
 "link": {
   "self": {
      "href": "http://local.dev-openclass.com:8088/v1/orders/search/?userId=ffffffff5e7c13a4da4a9d0132e95f73"
   }
 }
```

}

Comment: are you using `spring-data-rest` ?

Comment: No, I am not using spring-data-rest.

Comment: Did you upgrade the spring hateoas version  too?

Comment: As SpringBoot is upgraded to2.1.7, spring-hateoas is automatically upgraded to 0.25.2 (from 0.25.0).

Comment: Did you force mime type hal/json ?

Comment: @RequestMapping(method = GET, produces = "application/hal+json", value = "/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<?> findById(@PathVariable(value = "id") final String id) {
        long idLong = getLong(id, "orderId");
        Order order = orderService.findById(idLong);
        return order.map(OrderController::convertToResource)
                 .map(ResponseEntity::ok).orElse(ResponseEntity.notFound().build());
    }

Comment: public static Resource<Order> convertToResource(Order order) {
        final String id = String.valueOf(order.getId());
        Resource<Order> resource = new Resource<>(order);
        resource.add(linkTo(methodOn(OrderController.class).findById(id)).withSelfRel());
        resource.add(linkTo(methodOn(OrderController.class).findById(id)).withRel("order"));
        resource.add(linkTo(methodOn(OrderController.class)
            .findTransactionByOrderId(id)).withRel("transactions"));

        return resource;
    }

Comment: you really need to debug the generation of ResourceModel to JSON

Comment: The problem was caused by ObjectMapper in ApplicationContext. After remove it, it works.

Comment: Alright. Good to know